# One water pump control by four different switch from different souces

Tags: electrical

I have  a water pump to be controlled by four switches from different apartment of which each of the apartment have its own prepaid meter, please how do I go about this

Comment: what sort of meter (flow?, time? energy?)

Comment: What happens when the prepay runs out?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like a commercial installation (for an apartment complex) which is outside the realm of _Home_ Improvement.

Comment: How much energy is this pump going to use?  Do the apartments have separate electric meters and do you want each user to pay for the electricity use of the pump?  Reason I ask is, a system to split the metering *safely and legally* is going to cost *the landlord* about 10 times more than other more ... egalitarian ... solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use relays, one for each user.

That way they don't "backfeed" each other.

Based on the comment, have hour meters driven by how long the relay is energised - but you run into difficulties compared to who turned it on if others can also use it...

Comment: seems like a good start, but how do you meter that fairly?

Answer (score 1):

These days, I'd just throw some home automation hardware at the problem. Most such systems have a way to map multiple on/off switches to a single controlled device so that any switch can request the device be turned on or off. Fancier hardware can also tell all the other switches to update their status indicator so you know the current state at a glance.

Much simpler than trying to build it out of relays. Easier to wire. It would cost a bit more for the hardware, but given the reduction in complexity...